# How can I join these two tables to return the desired results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two queries which are returning the results I want, but I want to combine these into a single select statement via joins. I've gotten this far, but I'm still not that good at understanding joins so I need some help here.

Here is the first query:

```
SELECT aur.Asset_Id AS AssetId, pl.Program_Name AS AssetName, aur.Action,
aur.Action_Timestamp, u.name AS PrimaryUser, u1.name AS UpdatedByUser
FROM Audit_User_Roles aur
LEFT JOIN Users u ON aur.User_Id = u.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON aur.OUser_Id = u1.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Program_List pl ON pl.Asset_Id = aur.Asset_Id
WHERE aur.Role_Id = 1
ORDER BY AssetId, aur.Action_Timestamp DESC
```

Here is the second query:

```
SELECT asur.Asset_id AS AssetId, pl.Program_Name AS AssetName, asur.Action,
asur.Action_Timestamp, u.name AS SecondaryUser, asur.Environment, 
u1.name AS UpdatedByUser
FROM Audit_Secondary_User_Roles asur
LEFT JOIN Users u ON asur.Manager_User_Id = u.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON asur.OUser_Id = u1.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Program_List pl ON pl.Asset_Id = asur.Asset_Id
ORDER BY AssetId, asur.Action_Timestamp DESC
```

An example row of output from the first query:

```
| AssetId | AssetName | Action  | Action_Timestamp        | PrimaryUser | UpdatedByUser |
|    1    | TestProg  | Updated | 2014-12-11 13:25:27.483 | John Smith  | John Smith    |
```

An example row of output from the second query:

```
| AssetId | AssetName | Action | Action_Timestamp         | SecondaryUser | Environment | UpdatedByUser |
|    1    | TestProg  | Insert | 2014-12-02 11:48:41.862  | Jane Doe      | TstA1       | John Smith    |
```

What I want it to look like in a single result:

```
| AssetId | AssetName | Action  | Action_Timestamp        | PrimaryUser | SecondaryUser | Environment | UpdatedByUser |
|    1    | TestProg  | Updated | 2014-12-11 13:25:27.483 | John Smith  | NULL          | NULL        | John Smith    |
|    1    | TestProg  | Insert  | 2014-12-02 11:48:41.862 | NULL        | Jane Doe      | TstA1       | John Smith    |
```

How can I modify these queries to return these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't want a *join*, but rather a *union*:

```
SELECT aur.Asset_Id AS AssetId, pl.Program_Name AS AssetName, aur.Action,
aur.Action_Timestamp, u.name AS PrimaryUser, NULL AS SecondaryUser,
NULL AS Environment, u1.name AS UpdatedByUser
FROM Audit_User_Roles aur
LEFT JOIN Users u ON aur.User_Id = u.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON aur.OUser_Id = u1.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Program_List pl ON pl.Asset_Id = aur.Asset_Id
WHERE aur.Role_Id = 1
UNION
SELECT asur.Asset_id AS AssetId, pl.Program_Name AS AssetName, asur.Action,
asur.Action_Timestamp, NULL AS PrimaryUser, u.name AS SecondaryUser,
asur.Environment, u1.name AS UpdatedByUser
FROM Audit_Secondary_User_Roles asur
LEFT JOIN Users u ON asur.Manager_User_Id = u.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON asur.OUser_Id = u1.User_Id
LEFT JOIN Program_List pl ON pl.Asset_Id = asur.Asset_Id
ORDER BY AssetId, asur.Action_Timestamp DESC
```

Basically you just modify each query so that it has nulls in the "missing" columns (relative to the other query), then you tack them together using the `UNION` keyword. `ORDER BY` is only allowed at the end of the last query in the union — it orders all the rows without regard for which branch of the query each row came from — which in your case is perfect, since you had the same `ORDER BY` in each query anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I could just use the `NULL AS` to connect these two like that.